# Is it secure to use window.location.href directly in Angular

Tags: angular, scripting, xss, cross-site

Is it secure to use window.location.href without any validation?

For example:

```
    navigateUsingUrl(url: string) {
       window.location.href = url}
```

And calling this function:

```
    this.navigateUsingUrl('https://www.google.com')
```

**Checkmarx throwing this issue**
*This untrusted data is embedded straight into the output without proper sanitization or encoding, enabling an attacker to inject malicious code into the output.*

Comment: I guess it depends on where you get the `url` string from. If it's hardcoded, it should be safe.

Comment: I am using in below format:
const url = `${location.origin}/some/url`
and passing this url to navigateUsingUrl(url) method.

Comment: You can use it relatively: `window.location.href = '/some/url'`